# Is it possible to format numbers in a Data Frame without turning them into strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numbers, format

I would like to export a dataframe to Excel as xls and show numbers with a 1000 separator and 2 decimal places and percentages as % with 2 decimals, e.g. 54356 as 54,356.00 and 0.0345 as 3.45%

When I change the format in python using .map() and .format it displays them correctly in python, but it turns them into a string and when I export them to xls Excel does not recognize them as numbers/percentages.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Percent': [0.01, 0.0345], 'Number': [54464.43, 54356]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Percent'] = pd.Series(["{0:.2f}%".format(val * 100) for val in df['Percent']], index = df.index)

df['Number'] = df['Number'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

The data frame looks as expected, but the type of the cells is now str and if I export it to xls (df.to_excel('file.xls')), Excel shows the "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" warning.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but percent has its own formatting code. `df.Percent.map('{:.2%}'.format)`

Comment: When writing to excel you can specify `float_format`. Sadly, this is one format for all columns, and doesn't accept a dict of {col: format_str}, so it's not a perfect solution, given you need the % sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the style property when you display the DataFrame, but the underlying data is not touched

```py
df.style.format({
    'Number': '{0:.2f}'.format, 
    'Percent': '{0:.2%}'.format,
})
```

see: [pandas style guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your goal is the way how the actual cells in the output excel file are formatted. To do this, you may want to focus on the actual file rather than formatting within pandas DataFrame (i.e. your data is correct, the problem is the way they're displayed in the output).

You may want to try something like [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe lambda would be more helpful

```py
df['Percent'] = df['Percent'].apply(lambda x: round(x*100, 2))
df['Number'] = df['Number'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

- For **df["Number"]** : `df.Number = df.Number.apply(lambda x : '{0:,.2f}'.format(x))` will work
- For **df["Percent"]** : first multiply the series by 100. `df["Percent"] = df.Percent.multiply(100)`

  - Then use `df.Percent = df.Percent.apply(lambda x: "{0:.2f}%".format(x))`

Hope this helps